# Force kafka consumer to poll partition with highest lag

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a setup where several `KafkaConsumers` each handle a number of partitions on a single topic. They are statically assigned the partitions, in a way that ensures that each consumer has an equal number of partitions to handle. The record key is also chosen so that we have equal distribution of messages over all partitions.

At times of heavy load, we often see a small number of partitions build up a considerable lag (thousands of messages/several minutes worth), while other partitions that are getting the same load and are consumed by the same consumer manage to keep the lag down to a few hundred messages / couple of seconds.

It looks like the consumer is fetching records as fast as it can, going around most of the partitions, but now and then there is one partition that gets left out for a long time. Ideally, I'd like to see the lag spread out more evenly across the partitions.

I've been reading about `KafkaConsumer` poll behaviour and configuration for a while now, and so far I think there's 2 options to work around this:

1. Build something custom that can monitor the lag per partition, and use `KafkaConsumer.pause()` and `.resume()` to essentially force the `KafkaConsumer` to read from the partitions with the most lag
2. Restrict our `KafkaConsumer` to only ever subscribe to one `TopicPartition`, and work with multiple instances of `KafkaConsumer`.

Neither of these options seem like the proper way to handle this. Configuration also doesn't seem to have the answer:

- `max.partition.fetch.bytes` only specifies the max fetch size for a single partition, it doesn't guarantee that the next fetch will be from another partition.
- `max.poll.interval.ms` only works for consumer groups and not on a per-partition basis.

Am I missing a way to encourage the `KafkaConsumer` to switch partition more often? Or a way to implement a preference for the partitions with the highest lag?

Comment: Have you tried increasing `fetch.max.bytes`: _The maximum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. ... Note that the consumer performs multiple fetches in parallel. Default: 52428800_

Comment: Not yet, but you may have a point in that forcing it to make smaller and thus more frequent fetches may cause it to hit more partitions. I'll play around with that.

Comment: Was there ever a solution for this? I see an uneven distribution in fetched records too. Each poll seems to pull disproportionately from a single partition first and then the remaining ones get the extra space.

Comment: @jocull I think we either scaled to more consumers or made our processing more performant so that there was no noticeable lag to begin with. I can't verify because I no longer work on the code base where I encountered this issue, sorry.

Comment: @Mopper Now there is a `max.partition.fetch.bytes`  that you can configure to be a small value to enforce fetching messages from multiple partitions https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.partition.fetch.bytes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure wether the answer is still relevant to you or if my answer exactly replies to your needs, However, you could try a lag aware assignor. This assignor which assign partitions to consumers ensures that consumers are assigned partitions so that the lag among consumers is assigned uniformly/equally. Here is a well written code that I used it that implements a lag based assignor.

https://github.com/grantneale/kafka-lag-based-assignor

All what you need is to configure you consumer to use this assignor. The below statament.

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, LagBasedPartitionAssignor.class.getName());
```